# Error on accessing data from from Firebase Firestore in Flutter iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, I've done lots of researching across the internet, have tried **all** the solutions I could think off: `flutter clean`, `pod init, pod install pod update`, updating the security rules, and also re-adding the Google Services plist file multiple times through Xcode, editing AppDelegate.swift and adding the proper code, making sure to ensurewidgetbinding and initializing the FirebaseApp in main, updating my firebase packages, but this error still keeps popping up when trying to access Firestore data. Firestore auth works fine though, and although my app doesn't work on a iOS simulator, it works perfectly find on Android simulator.

I've been facing this issue from a number of days.

The key issue is: *** **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: threads > 1'**

Here are more details of the stack log:

> 2021-04-13 13:52:31.821705-0700 Runner[19143:118021] *** Assertion failure in static std::unique_ptr firebase::firestore::util::Executor::CreateConcurrent(const char *, int)(), /(my app path)/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/util/executor_libdispatch.mm:368
> 2021-04-13 13:52:31.914078-0700 Runner[19143:118021] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: threads > 1'
> *** First throw call stack:
> (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422ff2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422e1b +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
> 3   Foundation                          0x00007fff20774a20 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
> 4   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102cb2107 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 343
> 5   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102cb1665 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 53
> 6   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e06d7d _ZN8firebase9firestore4util8internal13FailAssertionEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 45
> 7   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e06e31 *ZN8firebase9firestore4util8internal13FailAssertionEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEES4* + 177
> 8   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102cb465e _ZN8firebase9firestore4util8Executor16CreateConcurrentEPKci + 94
> 9   FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e4afe7 _ZN8firebase9firestore5local26LevelDbRemoteDocumentCacheC2EPNS1_18LevelDbPersistenceEPNS1_15LocalSerializerE + 327
> 10  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e4b165 _ZN8firebase9firestore5local26LevelDbRemoteDocumentCacheC1EPNS1_18LevelDbPersistenceEPNS1_15LocalSerializerE + 37
> 11  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e44bc7 *ZN4absl14lts_2020_02_2511make_uniqueIN8firebase9firestore5local26LevelDbRemoteDocumentCacheEJPNS4_18LevelDbPersistenceEPNS4_15LocalSerializerEEEENS0_15memory_internal16MakeUniqueResultIT_E6scalarEDpOT0* + 103
> 12  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e44788 _ZN8firebase9firestore5local18LevelDbPersistenceC2ENSt3__110unique_ptrIN7leveldb2DBENS3_14default_deleteIS6_EEEENS0_4util4PathENS3_3setINS3_12basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEENS3_4lessISI_EENSG_ISI_EEEENS1_15LocalSerializerERKNS1_9LruParamsE + 536
> 13  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e4446d _ZN8firebase9firestore5local18LevelDbPersistenceC1ENSt3__110unique_ptrIN7leveldb2DBENS3_14default_deleteIS6_EEEENS0_4util4PathENS3_3setINS3_12basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEENS3_4lessISI_EENSG_ISI_EEEENS1_15LocalSerializerERKNS1_9LruParamsE + 29
> 14  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e439a4 _ZN8firebase9firestore5local18LevelDbPersistence6CreateENS0_4util4PathENS1_15LocalSerializerERKNS1_9LruParamsE + 932
> 15  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102e40260 _ZN8firebase9firestore5local13LevelDbOpener6CreateERKNS1_9LruParamsE + 640
> 16  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d3715b _ZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient10InitializeERKNS0_4auth4UserERKNS0_3api8SettingsE + 379
> 17  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d4198d _ZZZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient6CreateERKNS1_12DatabaseInfoERKNS0_3api8SettingsENSt3__110shared_ptrINS0_4auth19CredentialsProviderEEENSB_INS0_4util8ExecutorEEENSB_INSF_10AsyncQueueEEENSA_10unique_ptrINS0_6remote24FirebaseMetadataProviderENSA_14default_deleteISM_EEEEEN3$_2clENSC_4UserEENKUlvE_clEv + 61
> 18  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d4192d _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient6CreateERKNS3_12DatabaseInfoERKNS2_3api8SettingsENS_10shared_ptrINS2_4auth19CredentialsProviderEEENSC_INS2_4util8ExecutorEEENSC_INSG_10AsyncQueueEEENS_10unique_ptrINS2_6remote24FirebaseMetadataProviderENS_14default_deleteISN_EEEEEN3$*2clENSD_4UserEEUlvE_JEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSV_DpOSW* + 29
> 19  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d418dd _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient6CreateERKNS5_12DatabaseInfoERKNS4_3api8SettingsENS_10shared_ptrINS4_4auth19CredentialsProviderEEENSE_INS4_4util8ExecutorEEENSE_INSI_10AsyncQueueEEENS_10unique_ptrINS4_6remote24FirebaseMetadataProviderENS_14default_deleteISP_EEEEEN3$*2clENSF_4UserEEUlvE_EEEvDpOT* + 29
> 20  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d418ad _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient6CreateERKNS4_12DatabaseInfoERKNS3_3api8SettingsENS_10shared_ptrINS3_4auth19CredentialsProviderEEENSD_INS3_4util8ExecutorEEENSD_INSH_10AsyncQueueEEENS_10unique_ptrINS3_6remote24FirebaseMetadataProviderENS_14default_deleteISO_EEEEEN3$_2clENSE_4UserEEUlvE_NS_9allocatorISU_EEFvvEEclEv + 29
> 21  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102d404de _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZZN8firebase9firestore4core15FirestoreClient6CreateERKNS4_12DatabaseInfoERKNS3_3api8SettingsENS_10shared_ptrINS3_4auth19CredentialsProviderEEENSD_INS3_4util8ExecutorEEENSD_INSH_10AsyncQueueEEENS_10unique_ptrINS3_6remote24FirebaseMetadataProviderENS_14default_deleteISO_EEEEEN3$_2clENSE_4UserEEUlvE_NS_9allocatorISU_EEFvvEEclEv + 30
> 22  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1b685 _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvvEEclEv + 53
> 23  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c18c75 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvvEEclEv + 21
> 24  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c18bda _ZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue15ExecuteBlockingERKNSt3__18functionIFvvEEE + 186
> 25  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1da71 _ZZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue4WrapERKNSt3__18functionIFvvEEEENK3$_0clEv + 33
> 26  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1da2d _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIRZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue4WrapERKNS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$*0JEEEDTclclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT_Efp_Espclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_EEEOSC_DpOSD* + 29
> 27  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1d9dd _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue4WrapERKNS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$*0EEEvDpOT* + 29
> 28  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1d9ad _ZNSt3__110__function12__alloc_funcIZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue4WrapERKNS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_0NS_9allocatorISB_EES7_EclEv + 29
> 29  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1c72e _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8firebase9firestore4util10AsyncQueue4WrapERKNS_8functionIFvvEEEE3$_0NS_9allocatorISB_EES7_EclEv + 30
> 30  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c1b685 _ZNKSt3__110__function12__value_funcIFvvEEclEv + 53
> 31  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102c18c75 _ZNKSt3__18functionIFvvEEclEv + 21
> 32  FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010303ed15 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util4Task17ExecuteAndReleaseEv + 229
> 33  FirebaseFirestore                   0x0000000102cb308d _ZN8firebase9firestore4util19ExecutorLibdispatch11InvokeAsyncEPv + 29
> 34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010952374e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
> 35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109529f9a _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 796
> 36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010952ac67 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 436
> 37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000109536a7a _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 872
> 38  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff60250499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
> 39  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6024f467 start_wqthread + 15
> )
> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: threads > 1'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> CoreSimulator 757.3 - Device: iPhone 12 (B161D373-CDF3-4E02-A510-A7B855E99FBD) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E5164d) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
> (lldb)

Here is my flutter doctor -v results as well if needed:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5-0.0.pre.1, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64,
> locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.0.5-0.0.pre.1 at /Users/hassanwarsi/Desktop/flutter
> • Framework revision c63b72218f (6 days ago), 2021-04-07 22:46:48 -0700
> • Engine revision 2dce47073a
> • Dart version 2.12.2

> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at /Users/hassanwarsi/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
> • All Android licenses accepted.

> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.5, Build version 12E5244e
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

> [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
> ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

> [✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • iPhone 12 (mobile) • B161D373-CDF3-4E02-A510-A7B855E99FBD • ios •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator) ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

**Edit**

Here is the code sample I try to run -

````
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:gig/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'models/user.dart';
import 'screens/wrapper.dart';

Future<void> main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
 assert(app != null);
 print('Initialized default app $app');
runApp(MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MultiProvider(providers:[ 
 StreamProvider<User>.value(
               value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
               initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
 ),
         StreamProvider<UserData>(
               create: (context) => DatabaseService(uid:"${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser}").userData,
              // initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
         )]
 , child:
         MaterialApp(
   home: Wrapper()
 ));
}
} ```

Wrapper class -
````

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     while(Provider.of<User>(context)==null){return Loading();}
    print("user: ${Provider.of<User>(context)}");
    while( Provider.of<UserData>(context)==null){
      
      return Loading();
    }
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final userd = Provider.of<UserData>(context);
    return Container(child:Text("${userd.fname}")); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this error happening by any chance when you try to access subcollections? Or everytime you attempt using firestore? If it's not always, please post the relevant code causing this crash. Also, I would suggest running it on a physical iOS device to validate theories. If you don't have a physical device, does removing the firestore dependancy resolve the problem?

Comment: It happens every time I get anything from firestore, but I am able to get access to auth.  I have ran it on a physical iOS device using testflight, but it still crashes (it shows a black screen).  The cloud firestore dependency is necessary for the code to work of course, so I haven't removed it since otherwise, it causes errors.